longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length using case_when for date wrangling
I have a dummy dataset as follows.
my_data <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2022-03-08","2023-03-07","2022-11-29","2024-02-22")),
                      value = 1:4)

I have two vectors of dates as follows:
tox_date_1q <- as.Date(c("2022-03-08","2023-03-07","2024-02-21"))

tox_date_3q <- as.Date(c("2022-06-21","2022-09-14","2022-11-29","2023-06-05","2023-09-13","2023-11-14"))

I want to create a column group, and categorize each row with one of the following labels.
c("tox_date_1q", "tox_date_3q", "tox_period_1q", "tox_period_3q", "others")

my codes are the following:
my_data <- my_data |>
  mutate(group = case_when(
    date %in% tox_date_1q ~ "tox_date_1q",
    date %in% tox_date_3q ~ "tox_date_3q",
    date > as.Date(tox_date_1q-30) & date < as.Date(tox_date_1q+30) ~ "tox_period_1q",
    date > as.Date(tox_date_3q-30) & date < as.Date(tox_date_3q+30) ~ "tox_period_3q",
    .default = "other"
  ))

I received a warning message:
Warning message:
There were 4 warnings in `mutate()`.
The first warning was:
ℹ In argument: `group = case_when(...)`.
Caused by warning in `>.default`:
! longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Something wrong with the following codes, but I do not know how to fix it.
date > as.Date(tox_date_1q-30) & date < as.Date(tox_date_1q+30) ~ "tox_period_1q",
date > as.Date(tox_date_3q-30) & date < as.Date(tox_date_3q+30) ~ "tox_period_3q",


Can you explain what you want to achieve here date > as.Date(tox_date_1q-30) & date < as.Date(tox_date_1q+30) ~ "tox_period_1q"?  Your tox vectors list multiple dates.

I want to categorize data with tox_period_1q if associated date falls between the date range.

Given your input data, what is your expected output?

Hi Limey,  please see the output Andre provided.  That is what I expect.

Maybe you want to test if dates are greater than and lower than ALL tox_date_1q - 30 or tox_date_1q + 30
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

my_data %>% 
  mutate(group = case_when(
           date %in% tox_date_1q ~ "tox_date_1q", 
           date %in% tox_date_3q ~ "tox_date_3q", 
           map_vec(date, ~ all(.x > tox_date_1q - 30) & 
                           all(.x < tox_date_1q + 30)) ~ "tox_period_1q", 
           map_vec(date, ~ all(.x > tox_date_3q - 30) & 
                           all(.x < tox_date_3q + 30)) ~ "tox_period_3q", 
           .default = "other"))
        date value       group
1 2022-03-08     1 tox_date_1q
2 2023-03-07     2 tox_date_1q
3 2022-11-29     3 tox_date_3q
4 2024-02-22     4       other

Example where the 3rd test is true
my_data %>% 
  mutate(group = case_when(
           date %in% tox_date_1q ~ "tox_date_1q", 
           date %in% tox_date_3q ~ "tox_date_3q", 
           map_vec(date, ~ all(.x > tox_date_1q - 330) & 
                           all(.x < tox_date_1q + 1030)) ~ "tox_period_1q", 
           map_vec(date, ~ all(.x > tox_date_3q - 30) & 
                           all(.x < tox_date_3q + 30)) ~ "tox_period_3q", 
           .default = "other"))
        date value         group
1 2022-03-08     1   tox_date_1q
2 2023-03-07     2   tox_date_1q
3 2022-11-29     3   tox_date_3q
4 2024-02-22     4 tox_period_1q

Seems you want to test if one of the test (hence using OR) is all TRUE
my_data %>% 
  mutate(group = case_when(
           date %in% tox_date_1q ~ "tox_date_1q", 
           date %in% tox_date_3q ~ "tox_date_3q", 
           map_vec(date, ~ all(.x > tox_date_1q - 30) | 
                           all(.x < tox_date_1q + 30)) ~ "tox_period_1q", 
           map_vec(date, ~ all(.x > tox_date_3q - 30) | 
                           all(.x < tox_date_3q + 30)) ~ "tox_period_3q", 
           .default = "other"))
        date value         group
1 2022-03-08     1   tox_date_1q
2 2023-03-07     2   tox_date_1q
3 2022-11-29     3   tox_date_3q
4 2024-02-22     4 tox_period_1q

These are your tests from which you have to decide what you want to put out
my_data$date[4] > tox_date_1q - 30
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
my_data$date[4] < tox_date_1q + 30
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE

# e.g ALL TRUE OR ALL TRUE => TRUE
all(my_data$date[4] > tox_date_1q - 30) | all(my_data$date[4] < tox_date_1q + 30)
[1] TRUE

# e.g ALL TRUE AND ALL TRUE => FALSE
all(my_data$date[4] > tox_date_1q - 30) & all(my_data$date[4] < tox_date_1q + 30)
[1] FALSE

Same with tox_date_3q
Also note that if one test succeeds in case_when all subsequent tests are skipped.

@pinawa does not work, you get an error or is not what you intended?

I added a test to see if it works by subtracting and adding obvious values. Keep in mind you are testing one DATE against all tox_date_1q where all have to be lower when subtracting 30 AND all have to be higher when adding 30.

This tox_date_1q[1] for all entries 1:3 is exactly what map_vec in the code does.

my_data$date[4] < tox_date_1q - 30 is all c(F, F, F), my_data$date[4] > tox_date_1q + 30 is c(T, T, F).  What should the output be? all is testing if ALL values have been TRUE. What you're doing is taking ONE value of tox_date_1q and test that against ONE my_data$date. Do you want ONE to be true and then stop testing?

Then the last example with ANY and OR between the tests should be what you want.

Hi Andrew, I twisted a bit in your codes, and it works for me.  Here it is.   map_vec(date, ~ any(.x > tox_date_1q-30 &                .x < tox_date_1q+30)) ~ "tox_period_1q",      map_vec(date, ~ any(.x > tox_date_3q-30 &                .x < tox_date_3q+30)) ~ "tox_period_3q",

Unfortunately you can only accept one answer.

Here's a tidyverse take.
Inputs and a bigger toy data:
library(tidyverse)

# ----------------
# "Tox" inputs
tox_date_1q <- as.Date(c("2022-03-08","2023-03-07","2024-02-21"))
tox_date_3q <- as.Date(c("2022-06-21","2022-09-14","2022-11-29","2023-06-05","2023-09-13","2023-11-14"))

# ----------------
# Toy data
set.seed(100)

toy_data <- tibble(
  date = c(
    c(tox_date_1q, tox_date_3q), 
    sample(seq.Date(
      from = min(tox_date_1q, tox_date_3q) - days(90),
      to = max(tox_date_1q, tox_date_3q) + days(90),
      by = "days"), 
      20 - length(c(tox_date_1q, tox_date_3q)))),
  value = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE))

The code:
# ----------------
# Creating labels
new_data <- map_dfr(ls(pattern = "^tox"), \(x) tibble(date = get(x), label = x))

new_data <- map_dfr(
  1:nrow(new_data),
  \(x) bind_rows(
    new_data[x, ],
    tibble(
      date = new_data$date[x] + days(c(-30:-1, 1:30)), 
      label = str_replace(new_data$label[x], "date", "period"))))

# Labeling the data
new_data <- left_join(as_tibble(toy_data), new_data, by = "date") %>% 
  mutate(label = fct_na_value_to_level(factor(label), level = "others")) %>% 
  arrange(date)

The output:
# Output
new_data %>% 
  print(n = nrow(.))
#> # A tibble: 20 × 3
#>    date       value label        
#>    <date>     <int> <fct>        
#>  1 2021-12-14     7 others       
#>  2 2022-03-08     7 tox_date_1q  
#>  3 2022-03-15     6 tox_period_1q
#>  4 2022-06-21     3 tox_date_3q  
#>  5 2022-09-14     3 tox_date_3q  
#>  6 2022-11-29     8 tox_date_3q  
#>  7 2022-11-30     4 tox_period_3q
#>  8 2023-03-07     8 tox_date_1q  
#>  9 2023-03-22     7 tox_period_1q
#> 10 2023-04-24     4 others       
#> 11 2023-05-07     9 tox_period_3q
#> 12 2023-06-05     2 tox_date_3q  
#> 13 2023-08-23     4 tox_period_3q
#> 14 2023-09-13     9 tox_date_3q  
#> 15 2023-11-14     2 tox_date_3q  
#> 16 2023-11-21     3 tox_period_3q
#> 17 2023-11-25     5 tox_period_3q
#> 18 2024-02-21     2 tox_date_1q  
#> 19 2024-03-09     4 tox_period_1q
#> 20 2024-03-24     2 others

Created on 2024-04-26 with reprex v2.1.0

Thank you Adriano.  I appreciate your work.  I accepted both solutions and I prefer the shorter version.

Good, I'll leave an upvote to @Andre! Obs. This alternative works for any number of tox_date_  inputs.

Inspired by Andre Wildberg's solution, I twisted his solution and that works well.  Here you go.
my_data %>% 
  mutate(group = case_when(
           date %in% tox_date_1q ~ "tox_date_1q", 
           date %in% tox_date_3q ~ "tox_date_3q", 
           map_vec(date, ~ any(.x > tox_date_1q - 30 & 
                           .x < tox_date_1q + 30 ) ) ~ "tox_period_1q", 
           map_vec(date, ~ any(.x > tox_date_3q - 30 & 
                            .x < tox_date_3q + 30 ) ) ~ "tox_period_3q", 
           .default = "other" ) )

